# Matplotlib gridspec - placing another cubic plot right next to several subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

O am trying to work out how to place another plot, of a cubic shape, on the right of three subplots

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
gs1 = gridspec.GridSpec(3,2)
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs1[0, :])
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs1[1, :],sharex=ax1)
ax3 = plt.subplot(gs1[2, :],sharex=ax1)
plt.setp(ax1.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
plt.setp(ax2.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
plt.show()
```

[image]
How can I place another plot that spans the three rows next to those one using `gridspec`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already defined a proper splitting for the gridspec by subdividing it into two columns. Specify that the left axes use the first column (see changes below) and the axes which is supposed to be "cubic" (aspect ratio 1) uses the right column of your gridspec.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
gs1 = gridspec.GridSpec(3,2)
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs1[0, 0])
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs1[1, 0],sharex=ax1)
ax3 = plt.subplot(gs1[2, 0],sharex=ax1)
ax4 = plt.subplot(gs1[:, 1]) # NEW
ax4.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')  # NEW
plt.setp(ax1.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
plt.setp(ax2.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
plt.show()
```

[image: gridspec with two columns]

Alternatively, you could define a second gridspec and update the (relative) positioning of each gridspec, like so:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
gs1 = gridspec.GridSpec(3,2)
gs1.update(left=0.05, right=0.48, wspace=0.05)
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs1[0, :])
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs1[1, :],sharex=ax1)
ax3 = plt.subplot(gs1[2, :],sharex=ax1)

gs2 = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 1)
gs2.update(left=0.55, right=0.98, hspace=0.05)
ax4 = plt.subplot(gs2[0,0])
#ax4.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box') 
plt.setp(ax1.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
plt.setp(ax2.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
plt.show()
```

I commented the code to get an equal aspect ratio in `ax4`, to highlight that by default, it fills the entire available space.

[image: alternative gridspec]